# How to sort a Plist properly?

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

Well, I made a little game with give me at the end of the game, 3 datas.

Score, Coins, and Level. To this, I added the rank. (Which is manually done at the moment until I figure out how to change the rank # depending on the score)

So, here is the Plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"         "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>entry1</key>
<dict>
    <key>rank</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>level</key>
    <string>9</string>
    <key>score</key>
    <string>1999</string>
    <key>coins</key>
    <string>764</string>
</dict>
<key>entry2</key>
<dict>
    <key>rank</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>level</key>
    <string>8</string>
    <key>score</key>
    <string>1799</string>
    <key>coins</key>
    <string>375</string>
</dict>
<key>entry3</key>
<dict>
    <key>rank</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>level</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>score</key>
    <string>1599</string>
    <key>coins</key>
    <string>894</string>
</dict>
<key>entry4</key>
<dict>
    <key>rank</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>level</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>score</key>
    <string>799</string>
    <key>coins</key>
    <string>523</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I would like to be able to sort the highscore panels by rank, or coins, or level.

I've tried many things to achieve it but nothing does what I want.

So if anyone can give me some tips, I'll be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The property list is the format of the data in storage. To sort it, you should:

1. Read the data into an appropriate structure.
2. Sort the data in the structure.
3. Write the structure back out to a property list.

Using an appropriate structure is important. Property lists support two kinds of container objects: arrays and dictionaries. Arrays are ordered lists; dictionaries are unordered lists of key/value pairs. It looks like you're using a dictionary right now, with keys that indicate order. You should change your storage scheme to use an array instead. Then you can just sort the array according to score and write it out to a file.

Comment: Okay. But how to link a score with, for example, coins, or level, if this is "just" an array?
I mean, when I'll want to get back a data, I'll need a value, but all the other one that are linked to.

Comment: @user1183716: You've already got individual dictionaries that contain all of the information regarding the high scores. Just store those in an array in the order that you want them to be (i.e. ordered by score or by coins etc).

Comment: @user1183716 Each game should still be a dictionary, but you want an *array* of dictionaries, not a *dictionary* of dictionaries like you have now. The sample plist you showed has a dictionary at the top level with keys "entry1", "entry2", "entry3"... and the value for each of those keys is another dictionary. Put all those dictionaries in an array, sort the array according to their respective scores, and write to a file. Done.